# Why the margin-top can work?

Tags: html, css

```css
        

    div.box{
        width:105px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.box1{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.box2{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.box3{
        width:100px;
        clear:both;
        margin-top:20px;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
            <div class="box1">box1</div>
            <div class="box2">box2</div>
            <div class="box3">box3</div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Box1 and box2 are all floated left,and in box3 css ,all of them cleared.
Now box1 and box2 are on the top of box3,i want to insert margin space on box3 with `margin-top:20px;` in css of div.box3.
Why the margin-top can work?
I have accepted Narxx's answer ,some facts make me to cancel it as best answer,there are many elements to be floated in the real web page,many web pages are as long as 3000 line or more,so many floated boxes,we have to wrapp all the floated boxes when to clear the floating effect with the css code.

If there are 10 places to clear floating , the below css codes will be written for 10 times and to add 10 containers to contain boxes,it is tedious,how to simplify the action?

```
        div.container:after{
            clear:both;
            display:block;
            content:"";
            }
```

Maybe luboskrnac's way is better.

Comment: This solution is not good. First of all, it's wrong because it doesn't explain how the previous floats affect box3, and it doesn't really give a scalable solution to the problem, but a hard code workaround for this specific example. In a more complicated scenario - this answer would be impossible to implement.

Comment: @Harry The original task was to set 'x' pixels margin-top from whatever element above it, trying to clear previous floats. Suggesting to set that margin to the height of the taller element is not scalable because the height could be dynamic and that means going outside the scope of CSS to JS, making rendering the page harder and for no reason. You do not know that the previous floated elements have fixed heights and therefore cannot assume that. The solution should (and could, as I have demonstrated in my answer) be generic and allow previous floated elements to be in any size. Fixed or not.

Comment: @Harry As stated in w3schools: "Elements after a floating element will flow around it. To avoid this, use the clear property.": http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp so box2 is floated and box3 is after box2, therefore it's affected by it because this is how float is designed.

Comment: @Harry Okay, I see now what you meant. Yes, I could go deeper explaining how floating works, to make the answer more complete. I will consider adding an explanation to my answer.

Comment: @Narxx: That would be helpful for all if you could do :) I am kind of insisting on an explanation for that because the spec says - *Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse* (so, the margin exists, is not collapsed but is just not visible - which is why I said to set it to a higher value). Also as indicated earlier, I am removing my comments  and you can do so too, if you wish to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clear` should be used in a `div` under the two floated elements, but not in the `box3`. `clear` ["specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear).

You can add a `div` that will `clear: both;` (move down everything), so that it will move down everything after the floated elements

css:

```
.box{
    width:105px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
  }

.box1{
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.box2{
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.box3{
  width:100px;
  margin-top:20px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

html

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1">box1</div>
  <div class="box2">box2</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="box3">box3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: user3097405's answer is the best for my question ,it is  more simple than others,and achieved my target.

Answer (score 0):

You clear the float on box3, so from box3, there are no floats, but box3 itself is effected by the previous floats.
You should wrap the floating elements with a container, and make sure that after its content, there is a clear.

```css
    div.container:after {
       clear: both;
       display: block;
       content: " ";
    }

    div.box{
        width:105px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.box1{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.box2{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.box3{
        width:100px;
        margin-top:20px;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="box1">box1</div>
                <div class="box2">box2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="box3">box3</div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: If there are 10 places to clear floating , the below css codes will be written for 10 times and to add 10 containers to contain boxes,it is tedious,how to simplify the action? 
 
Maybe luboskrnac's way is better.

Comment: Rename 'container' with 'clearfix' and this is basically what bootstrap does. Create the class once, and use it anywhere needed. This way, in my experience, is better.

Comment: luboskrnac didn't really answer the problem but hacked around it assuming stuff that isn't given in your question. If it works for you, so be it, but I tried to give the best, most generic answer that will fit all unknowns given on your post.